# Freeglut Reshape callback

Tags: c++, freeglut

I am not using glutMainLoop() in my program but I am using glutMainLoopEvent() in a simple while loop. This is fine but the reshape callback is never called. I register my reshape event in the main(). Here's my source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GL/freeglut.h"


float angle = 0.0f;


void ResizeEvent(int w, int h)
{
    std::cout << "Resizing... << w << " " << h << std::Endl;

    if(h == 0)
        h = 1;

    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0, (GLdouble)w / h, 0.1, 100.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void InitializeGL()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0f);
    glViewport(0, 0, 640, 480);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0, 640.0 / 480.0, 0.1, 100.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void Update()
{
    angle += 0.05f;
}

void Display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f);
    glRotatef(angle, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.75f);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
        glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
        glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutCreateWindow("Learning freeglut");

    InitializeGL();

    glutReshapeFunc(ResizeEvent);

    while(true)
    {
        Update();

        Display();

        glutMainLoopEvent();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Anyone?

Comment: Does the reshape function get called if you use glutMainLoop()?

Comment: Yes. I try with other events like the keyboard event and it works with glutMainLoop and glutMainLoopEvent.

Answer (score 0):

`glutReshapeFunc` requires `glutDisplayFunc` to be set to *something*. This can even be an empty function as long as you don't need the window to update *while* resizing.

Possible solution

```
    ...

    glutReshapeFunc(ResizeEvent);

    glutDisplayFunc(Display);

    while(true)
    {
        Update();

        Display();

        glutMainLoopEvent();
    }

    ...
```